# Get a reference to service data in controller from async request (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, model-view-controller

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around data sharing between controllers. What I want to do is fetch data from a database (through a $http request), store it in a service variable, then share it between different controllers. From what I understand, that would allow my view to update automatically as the data is modified.

It seems quite easy with variables simply declared inside a service and accessed through a getter by the controllers. But the data I'm trying to share comes from an async operation, and I'm struggling to access it.

I came up with the following code, and I don't understand why I keep getting an "undefined" variable.

File: userController.js

```
function userController($scope, user)  //user = userService
{
    user.getChallengeList(25)
    .then(function(defiList)
    {
        $scope.allDefis = defiList;
        console.log($scope.allDefis);  //ok
        console.log(user.allDefis);  //undefined
    });
}
```

File: userService.js

```
function userService($http)
{
    this.allDefis;

    this.getChallengeList = function(id)
    {
        return $http
        .post('http://localhost:3131/defi/defiList', {'id': id})
        .then(function(response)
        {
            this.allDefis = response.data;
            return this.allDefis;
        });
    }
}
```

From this piece of code, shouldn't the allDefis variable be accessible inside the controller?

Doesn't using .then in the controller "force" it to wait for the getChallengeList() method to be executed?

In that case, why is the user.allDefis variable undefined?

I think I could be solving this problem by using $rootscope, but I'd prefer not to, as it doesn't seem like a recommended solution.

Comment: I think the issue is that within `getChallengeList`, and within the code block inside the `then`, `this` is not the `this` you are expecting.  I would try defining `var _this = this;` before the post, and then setting `allDefis` via `_this.allDefis = response.data`

Comment: It was indeed the source of the problem. I don't really get the reason though.
Do you know why it doesn't refer to the original this?

Comment: Because `this` in your anonymous function is scoped to the function passed into `then`, rather than the `this` that is scoped outside the function.  I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue lies in your implementation of `getChallengeList`:

```
this.getChallengeList = function(id)
{
    return $http
    .post('http://localhost:3131/defi/defiList', {'id': id})
    .then(function(response)
    {
        this.allDefis = response.data; //<-- this is scoped here
        console.log(this.allDefis);
        return this.allDefis;
    });
}
```

When you assign the web request response data to `allDefis`, the `this` is scoped to be within the anonymous function, rather than the overall function.

A technique to address this is to define a local variable that points to `this`, and use it instead.

You would adjust your implementation like this:

```
this.getChallengeList = function(id)
{
    var _this = this; // a reference to "this"

    return $http
    .post('http://localhost:3131/defi/defiList', {'id': id})
    .then(function(response)
    {
        _this.allDefis = response.data; // now references to correct scope
        console.log(this.allDefis);
        return this.allDefis;
    });
}
```